# What is a projection layer in the context of neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, neural-network, word2vec

I am currently trying to understand the architecture behind the *word2vec* neural net learning algorithm, for representing words as vectors based on their context.

After reading [Tomas Mikolov paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.3781v3.pdf) I came across what he defines as a **projection layer**. Even though this term is widely used when referred to *word2vec*, I couldn't find a precise definition of what it actually is in the neural net context.

[image: Word2Vec Neural Net architecture]

My question is, in the neural net context, what is a projection layer? Is it the name given to a hidden layer whose links to previous nodes share the same weights? Do its units actually have an activation function of some kind?

￼Another resource that also refers more broadly to the problem can be found in [this tutorial](http://www.coling-2014.org/COLING%202014%20Tutorial-fix%20-%20Tomas%20Mikolov.pdf), which also refers to a *projection layer* around page 67.

Comment: "this tutorial" link dead!

Comment: "Using Neural Networks for Modelling and Representing Natural Languages" tutorial link, the one in the questions does not work: http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~diana/csi5386/mikolov1,coling,2014,tutorial,fix,tomas,mikolov.pdf

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I find the previous answers here a bit overcomplicated - a projection layer is just a simple matrix multiplication, or in the context of NN, a regular/dense/linear layer, without the non-linear activation in the end (sigmoid/tanh/relu/etc.) The idea is to **project** the (e.g.) 100K-dimensions discrete vector into a 600-dimensions continuous vector (I chose the numbers here randomly, "your mileage may vary"). The exact matrix parameters are learned through the training process.

What happens before/after already depends on the model and context, and is not what OP asks.

(In [practice](https://youtu.be/VkjSaOZSZVs) you wouldn't even bother with the matrix multiplication (as you are multiplying a 1-hot vector which has 1 for the word index and 0's everywhere else), and would treat the trained matrix as a lookout table (i.e. the 6257th word in the corpus = the 6257th row/column (depends how you define it) in the projection matrix).)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Plain and simple answer, and explain why it is called "projection"; it is simply projecting a higher dimensional vector onto a lower dimensional space.

Comment: Do we add bias parameters after  matrix multiplication?

Comment: @AshishAggarwal not that I'm aware of.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, "projection layer" is also sometimes used to mean a dense layer that outputs a *higher-dimensional* vector than before (which ... isn't a projection), particularly when going from a hidden representation to an output representation. Diagrams then show a projection followed by a softmax, even though the latter is just the activation of the former, and they are actually one big layer.

Answer (score 26):

> The projection layer maps the discrete word indices of an n-gram context to a continuous vector space.

As explained in this [thesis](http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/%7Ewjb31/ppubs/gwbthesis2010.pdf)

> The projection layer is shared such that for contexts containing the same word multiple times, the same set of weights is applied to form each part of the projection vector.
> This organization effectively increases the amount of data available for training the projection layer weights since each word of each context training pattern individually contributes changes to the weight values.

[image]

this figure shows the trivial topology how the output of the projection layer can be efficiently assembled by copying columns from the projection layer weights matrix.

Now, the Hidden layer:

> The hidden layer processes the output of the projection layer and is also created with a
> number of neurons specified in the topology configuration file.

*Edit*: An explanation of what is happening in the diagram

> Each neuron in the projection layer is represented by a number of weights equal to the size of the vocabulary. The projection layer differs from the hidden and output layers by not using a non-linear activation function. Its purpose is simply to provide an efficient means of projecting the given n- gram context onto a reduced continuous vector space for subsequent processing by hidden and output layers trained to classify such vectors. Given the one-or-zero nature of the input vector elements, the output for a particular word with index i is simply the ith column of the trained matrix of projection layer weights (where each row of the matrix represents the weights of a single neuron).

Comment: Hello, the thesis link is broken. Do you mind helping to fix it?

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

The `continuous bag of words` is used to predict a single word given its prior and future entries: thus it is a contextual result.

The inputs are the computed weights from the prior and future entries: and all are given new weights identically: thus the complexity / features count of this model is much smaller than many other NN architectures.

RE: `what is the projection layer`: from the paper you cited

> the non-linear hidden layer is removed and the projection layer is
>   shared for all words (not just the projection matrix); thus, all words
>   get projected into the same position (their vectors are averaged).

So the projection layer is a single set of `shared weights` and no activation function is indicated.

> Note that the weight matrix between the input and the projection layer
>   is shared for all word positions in the same way as in the NNLM

So the `hidden layer` is in fact represented by this single set of shared weights - as you correctly implied that is identical across all of the input nodes.