# Feedforward Neural Net Language model - computational complexity (word2vec)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, nlp, word2vec

I was reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3781) on word2vec, and came around the following description of a feedforward NNLM:

> It consists of input, projection, hidden and output layers. At the input layer, N previous words are encoded using 1-of-V coding, where V is size of the vocabulary. The input layer is then projected to a projection layer P that has dimensionality N × D, using a shared projection matrix. As only N inputs are active at any given time, composition of the projection layer is a relatively cheap operation.

The following expression is given for the computational complexity per training example:

> Q = N×D + N×D×H + H×V.

The last two terms make sense to me: N×D×H is roughly the amount of parameters in a dense layer from the N×D-dimesnional projection layer to the H hidden neurons, analogous for H×V. The first term, however, I expected to be V×D since the mapping from a one-hot encoded word to a D-dimensional vector is done via a V×D dimensional matrix. I came to that conclusion after reading [this referenced paper](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/bengio03a/bengio03a.pdf) and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37937675/7952998) where the workings of the projection layer are explained in more detail.

Perhaps I have misunderstood what is meant by "training complexity".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this excerpt correctly, it is `N x D` because *N* previous words are taken into account, so you don't just test for one word, nor do you test for all words (*V*). Instead your input consists of *N* words. Therefore `N x D` is the complexity of this layer

Comment: Further, while the one-hot-to-per-word-dense-vector matrix is indeed `VxD` in *space*, as the questioner notes, that's not the magnitude of any computational effort per example. The lookup of word-vectors from that array is done via an amortized constant-time – O(1) – dictionary-lookup.

Comment: I agree with the O(1) complexity when evaluating the projection layer, but the formula in my question deals with the training complexity as I understand it. The look-up table has a VxD dimension, which means VxD weights that need to be updated per training example.

Comment: I have reposted this qusetion on SE Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/571435/319140